# Proving $\ln e = 1$

Tags: real-analysis

Using the definition $$ \ln x = \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}, $$ is it possible to show that $\ln e = 1$ without showing first that $\exp$ and $\ln$ are inverse functions? Here, $e$ is defined by the series $$ e = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}. $$

---

EDIT: A useful intermediate step in showing this result is $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = e. $$ However, the usual proof of this limit by L'Hospital's rule uses the fact that $\exp$ and $\ln$ are inverse functions. Is there an alternate proof that does not require the inverse property?

Remember, we are working from the series definition of $e$ stated above.

Comment: $$\ln e=\log_ee=1$$

Comment: Sure, but how is the function $\log_e$ defined?

Comment: If $\ln(x)=\log_e(x)=y$, then $e^y=x$. Now we know that $y=1$, therefore $e^1=x$, which means $e=x$. That means $\log_e(e)=1$, which then means $\ln(e)=1$

Comment: I am specifically asking if we can show $\ln e = 1$ without using the fact that $\exp$ and $\ln$ are inverses. In other words, I would like to know if we can directly evaluate the integral definition of $\ln e$.

Comment: Can we use ln(a^b)=bln(a)?

Comment: @DavidZhang Can we use L'Hospital's rule?

Comment: @Awesome I'm not sure; can it be shown without using the fact that $\exp$ and $\ln$ are inverses? I just tried, and I can only show it for integer $b$.

Comment: If we know that derivative of a^x is a^x ln(a) we can taylor expand

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Sure, L'Hospital's is fine. This isn't some sort of draconian homework where not using inverses is a requirement, I'm just genuinely curious.

Comment: @Awesome I believe that requires the use of $\exp$ and $\ln$ being inverses. If you can provide a proof without using this fact, then feel free to use it.

Comment: @DavidZhang It only requires use of the property above mentioned. Can we in between prove that they are inverses using only properties you mentioned?

Comment: @Awesome If you have to use the inverse property as an intermediate step, then the proof isn't entirely what I'm looking for. However, I'm interested in your approach, so you can go ahead and post your answer.

Comment: I think that [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function) is *exactly* what you need.

Answer (score 5):

We have $\displaystyle \ln(x)=\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$.  Set $\displaystyle g(x)=\sum_n \frac{x^n}{n!}$. Then $g(1)=e$, $g'(x)=g(x)$, and so $\ln(g(x))'=\ln'(g(x))g'(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)}g(x)=1$, hence $\ln(g(x))=x+c$. Since $g(0)=1$ and $\ln(1)=0$, we have $c=0$, hence $\ln(g(x))=x$, and so $\ln(e)=\ln(g(1))=1$.

Comment: You have just proven exactly the result I wish not to use. I am seeking a proof of $\ln e = 1$ without using that $\exp$ and $\ln$ are inverses.

Comment: @DavidZhang Where did I use the fact that $\exp$ and $\ln$ are inverses?

Comment: Your $g(x)$ is exactly the definition of $\exp x$.

Comment: +1: This answer doesn't use the fact that $\exp$ and $\ln$ are inverses.

Comment: @copper.hat Yes it does. Re-labeling $\exp x$ as $g(x)$ and then showing that $g$ and $\ln$ are inverses is equivalent to simply using the fact that $\exp$ and $\ln$ are inverses.

Comment: It does not. Showing that they are inverses and using the fact that they are are different things. You are **asking** to show that they are inverses at $t=0$ (or whatever), so you cannot escape showing that they are in some sense.

Comment: My apologies; my last comment was not very clear. What I mean to say is that this proof uses exactly the strategy used to prove that $\exp x$ and $\ln x$ are inverses. It simply picks out the particular case $x=1$ to show the desired result. While technically correct, this is not what I am looking for; after all, any question in the form "prove $x$ without using $y$" can be answered by proving $y$ for the particular case $x$. However, I will agree that this proof **does** answer the question as stated.

Answer (score 1):

It can be shown quite easily (must add: using ONLY the binomial theorem, grumpy kid) that $$e=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(1+1/k)^k$$

If you don't want to get too picky about mathematical rigor, you will accept the following steps

$$\ln (\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(1+1/k)^k)=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\ln ((1+1/k)^k)$$

$$ =\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}k\ln ((1+1/k))$$
$$ =\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln ((1+1/k))}{1/k}$$
$$ =\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{\ln (1+u)}{u}$$

Applying L'hospital and the fundamental theorem of calculus

$$ =\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{u+1}=1$$

Comment: I accept that you have shown $\ln \lim_{k \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{k})^k = 1$. However, how does this show that $\lim_{k \to \infty} (1 + \frac{1}{k})^k = e$ as defined above? I believe you have implicitly made use of $\ln$ and $\exp$ being inverses.

Comment: No, I have not. As I said 'It can be shown quite easily', that's why I didn't write that part. Just make a binomial expansion of $(1+1/k)^k=1+k \frac{1}{k}+\frac{(k)(k-1)}{2}\frac{1}{k^2}+...$, take the limit term by term, and you will get the first equation I wrote.

Comment: ok, @DavidZhang? come on, I want to go sleeping already

Comment: Nobody's saying you need to stay up and monitor the question.

Comment: hahahah come on... don't be so grumpy!   but you didn't say if my last comment seemed enough to you or why not

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to come off as rude. The binomial expansion does work, but I have one more question: how can it be shown that $\ln a^b = b \ln a$ without using the inverse property? I can only prove this for integer $b$.

Comment: No, never mind. It suffices to show it for integer $b$. I'm not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition, we have
$$
e = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n.
$$
Now, applying $\ln$ both sides.
$$
\begin{align}
\ln e &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n\\
\ln e&=\lim_{n \to \infty}n\ln\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right).
\end{align}
$$
Let $\dfrac{1}{n}=x\;\Rightarrow\; n=\dfrac{1}{x}$. As $n\to\infty$, $x\to0$, then
$$
\ln e=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln\left(1 + x\right)}{x}.
$$
Now you can apply L'Hospital's rule to the RHS. I hope this helps.

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: See my edit. I do not believe your first step can be justified without using the inverse property.

Comment: @DavidZhang I thought this that you were looking for that's why I asked you in the comment below. It's OK. My fault... **:)**

Comment: Actually, after seeing some other answers, the first step can indeed be justified without using inverses by using binomial expansion.

Answer (score 1):

One can show that $e = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac 1n\right)^n$ using only the binomial theorem.

1. Consider $a_n = (1 + \frac 1n )^n$.
2. By the binomial theorem, 
   $$\begin{align}
   a_n &= \sum_{0 \leq k \leq n} {n \choose k} \left( \frac 1n \right)^k \\
   &= 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!}(1 - \frac 1n) + \frac{1}{3!}(1 - \frac 1n)(1 - \frac 2n) + \ldots + \frac{1}{n!}(1 - \frac 1n)\cdots(1 - \frac{n-1}{n}).
   \end{align}$$

   From this, it's quite easy to see that $a_n < a_{n+1}$ and $a_n < e$ using your definition of $e$, so this limit exists.
3. Fix some $m$ and consider the terms just up to $nm$:
   $$ 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!}(1 - \frac 1n) + \dots + \frac{1}{m!}(1 - \frac 1n)\cdots(1 - \frac{m-1}{n}),$$
   which is clearly less than $a_n$, and as $n \to \infty$, this goes to
   $$ 1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \dots + \frac{1}{m!}.$$
   As we can do this for any $m < n$, taking the limits as $n \to \infty$ and then $m \to \infty$ gives us that $e \leq \lim a_n \leq e$, or that $e = \lim a_n$, which is what I sought to prove.

Now we see this doesn't use that exponentials and logarithms are inverses at all, and completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $e= \lim_{n \to +\infty}(1+\frac 1n)^{n}$.

Consider $\frac d{dx}(ln x)=\lim_{h \to0}\frac {ln(x+h)-ln(x)}h\ =\ lim_{h \to 0}\frac {ln(\frac {x+h}x)}h$ = $\lim_{h \to0}\frac 1hln(1+\frac hx)$

Let $u=\frac xh$ hence as $h\to 0$, $u\to \infty$. Thus we have

$\frac d{dx}(ln x)=\lim_{u \to +\infty}(\frac ux(ln(1+\frac 1u)))$ = $\lim_{u \to +\infty} (\frac 1x(ln(1+\frac 1u)^{u})$ = $\frac 1x lne$.

Now integrate both sides to get the result.